# Can a general verb ‘have’ be in front of a question?

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence, isn’t the verb ‘have’ a general verb? Isn’t it correct to change like “Do you have any commissions for Egypt?”

> “Have 
>   you any commissions for Egypt?”

Comment: ***have*** here is used to imply "ownership, possession" as opposed to being a general-purpose "helper" auxiliary verb *(I **have** been to London, The rain **has** stopped, etc.)*. But although the phrasing as cited is "grammatical", it's increasingly seen as "old-fashioned" and/or excessively formal for most contexts. Children are still "taught" the usage *(Baa baa black sheep, **have** you any wool?)*, but in practice they mostly just repeat what they hear others use in normal conversation: ***Do you have** any...?* in BrE or ***Have you got** any...?* in AmE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of "Have" in questions "Do you have" or "Have you"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/101667/use-of-have-in-questions-do-you-have-or-have-you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [1] *Do you have any commissions for Egypt?*
>
> [2] *Have you any commissions for Egypt?*

No: when "have" expresses such meanings as possession or obligation it can be either a lexical verb (your 'general' verb) or an auxiliary verb.

Grammatically, in closed questions like these, lexical "have" requires the addition of the dummy auxiliary verb "do" as in [1], while auxiliary "have" in [2] does not.

Most speakers treat "have" as a lexical verb, or use the informal idiom "have got" as in "Have you got any ...", where the "have" component is an auxiliary verb.